# How to use the LIKE statement correctly in a MySql SELECT statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, wildcard, sql-like

Why isn't this working?

```
DELIMITER ;//

CREATE PROCEDURE `blah`
(
  SearchText varchar(4000)
)
BEGIN
  SELECT *
  FROM table_name
  WHERE table_name.StringField LIKE '%' + SearchText + '%'; -- This is where the code is breaking
END;//
```

Comment: Have you tried quoting the like? '\'%' + SearchText + '%\''

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using:

```
CONCAT('%', SearchText ,'%')
```

Comment: +1  MySQL does not support "+" as a string concatenation operator.  That's a Microsoft/Sybase thing.

Comment: Indeed.  The SQL standard also defines the || operator for character string (and bit string) concatenation, which is the way I'm used to seeing it done.

Comment: Awesome. Yeah I come from a MSSQL background so I kind of take that for granted. Once I'm finished with this project, I'm going to create a wiki entry "Top 20 things you should know when converting MSSQL to MySQL"